# How to convert MS Word to PDF in the web browser

Tags: pdf, ms-word, pdf-generation, client-side, file-conversion

I've seen others ask this but I think my requirement is the most strict yet:

I need to programmatically convert MS Word .DOC (Office 2003 or earlier) or .DOCX (Office 2007 or later) files into PDF files. This needs to happen on an ad-hoc basis over time - not once, not with a set of files sitting on my desktop right now.

My platform runs in the cloud, so I have no server on which to run one of the many server-side conversion tools out there and I cannot write a VB or C# or Java application in which to make this happen. For instance, I cannot use Aspose.words or Libre Office since I have no computer on which to install them or an app that uses them.

I am thinking I need a **client-side**, web browser-based solution, JavaScript for instance. Is there such a library? From the other questions I see have been asked here over the last couple of years, I think the answer is no, but I thought I'd better check to be sure.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are searching for a *client-side, web browser-based solution,* your tags are not appropriate to be found by the corresponding experts. That being said, I doubt you'll find a pure browser-based (e.g. JavaScript) solution, especially for high-accuracy requirements. Maybe some ActiveX component using a locally installed MS Word? This, of course, would limit the number of clients for your application; and it would be less trustworthy. Maybe a big Java Web Start application integrating numerous libraries would also be a solution...

Answer (score 1):

The Docmosis Cloud service can do doc/docx -> pdf from JavaScript.  You can have a doc/docx converted (rendered) by posting a https request with a JSON payload.  Please note I work for the company that created Docmosis.

I hope that helps.